# XML file won't validate to XSD

Tags: xml, xsd-validation

If I can't make it validate my prof won't mark it, and I cannot seem to make this work, any help much appreciated. I'm using xmlvalidation as its the only one I'm allowed to use according to the instructions.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

<MikeDawidowski xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=" Company-withErrors.xsd">

  <company ORDER="1">
   <CompanyName>TestCompany</CompanyName>  
    <CID>1</CID>
    <City>London</City>
    <Prov>ON</Prov>
    <MaterialSource>
        <MaterialBrandName>Leather</MaterialBrandName>
        <MaterialIdentification>105</MaterialIdentification>
        <AssocCompID>10</AssocCompID>
        <MaterialBrandName>Leather2</MaterialBrandName>
        <MaterialIdentification>110</MaterialIdentification>
        <AssocCompID>15</AssocCompID>
    </MaterialSource>
    <PhoneNum>5196867766</PhoneNum>
  </company>

</MikeDawidowski>
```

and this is the XSD

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="MikeDawidowski"> 
    <xs:complexType>
                <xs:sequence>
                </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


            <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="CompanyName" type="xs:string" />

                <xs:element name="CID" type="xs:integer"  />  

                <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" minOccurs = "0"/> 
                <xs:element name="Prov" type="xs:string" minOccurs = "0"/>
                <xs:element name="MaterialSource" maxOccurs="5">
                    <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="MaterialBrandName" type="xs:string" />
                        <xs:element name="MaterialIdentification" type="xs:string" />                       

                    </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

                <xs:element name="PhoneNum" type="xs:string" minOccurs = "0"/>                      

            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="ORDER" type="xs:integer" use="optional"/>
            </xs:complexType>



</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Can you confirm the XSD file name is ` Company-withErrors.xsd` and it's in the same folder with XML? Note: There is a space char in the beginning of `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation`.

Comment: @beckyang yeah, I just took out the space and made sure the were in the same folder with the proper names, when I go to validate I get these errors: Errors in the XML document: 
 22: 18 cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'MikeDawidowski' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

Errors in file xml-schema: 
 13: 20 s4s-att-must-appear: Attribute 'name' must appear in element 'complexType'.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways in XSD of saying what the type of an element should be, and you've got some mixture of the two. The first is to put the type information inline, in which case the type doesn't have a name:

```
<xs:element name="MikeDawidowski"> 
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element....
           <xs:element....
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The second way is to define a named type and refer to it:

```
<xs:element name="MikeDawidowski" type="myType"/> 

<xs:complexType name="myType">
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element....
           <xs:element....
        </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

You've somehow contrived to put all the type information out-of-line from the element declaration, but you haven't actually given the type a name or linked to it from the element declaration.